# Rails - custom timezone prevents from getting timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, timezone

I'm using Devise and Grape

I'm facing a problem with timezones. Whenever i set timezone in environment:

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Dubai'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Asia/Dubai'
```

When I get a record from the DB and try to access one of the timestamps I get

```
User.first
User.reset_password_sent_at
#=> nil
```

And the weirdest part of this is that I see the column filled with valid timestamp in the DB.

I tried to run an update manually via Rails Console. After successfully updating the record i ran a reload and the **reset_password_sent_at** vanished. Again I got "nil".

What can be the cause of this and how can i overcome?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the cause.

I set the

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Dubai'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Asia/Dubai'
```

where i should just set the time of the application, not ActiveRecord. So in the config it should look like:

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Dubai'
```

Now i'm getting data back from the database.